# Delete tables using SQL query based on table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have 1000 tables in my SQL Server database. Table names like CIP_01_12_2022_10_15_20 that I have 1000 table. Table name saved as data time(CIP_DD_MM_YYYY_HH_MM_SS).

So I need to delete like between particular dates.

Tables named like below

```
CIP_01_12_2022_10_15_20
CIP_01_12_2022_10_15_25
CIP_01_12_2022_10_15_35
CIP_01_12_2022_10_15_45
CIP_01_12_2022_10_15_55
CIP_01_12_2022_10_15_58
CIP_01_12_2022_10_15_59
CIP_01_12_2022_10_16_20
CIP_01_12_2022_10_16_25
CIP_02_12_2022_10_15_20
```

In the above, I have to delete between two dates. For example I have to delete between these dates 01-12-2022 00:00:00 to 01-12-2022 11:59:59 delete all tables except 2nd December 2022 table.

Comment: Table names can't be parameters. You'll have to construct and execute a SQL command for every table.  That's a bad design to begin with. SQL Server allows transparent table partitioning in all supported versions and editions - even Express. You can create time-based partitions on the `CIP` table that are invisible to applications and just remove the partitions you don't want. Or issue normal DELETE commands

Comment: You could create an updateable view with `UNION ALL` and use `DELETE` with it. I'm not sure if you can use 1000 tables though. You'll also have to ensure each table has `CHECK` constraints that limit the possible date values, otherwise the server will have to scan all tables for matches. On the other hand, you already try to do that by hand

Comment: Unless each table is very large, partitioning may well be overkill. Simply inserting rows with the appropriate timestamp in *one* destination table and using a regular old `DELETE` likely suffices. The ingesting process may need to become a little bit more complicated for that, but that's well worth the effort as opposed to sorting this out in T-SQL after the fact.

Comment: How many rows are there? Why are 1000 tables used at all ? Unless there are 1Bn (Billion) rows, there's no need for 1000 partitions, much less 1000 tables. Definitely not a table per second

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos unfortunately wrong data created with huge tables.. every table we have 50 rows.

Comment: Then you need to fix the bug, not cover it up. Executing 1000 DELETEs in a loop will be very expensive, even if the tables are empty. 50K rows is no data at all. That's so little data it can easily fit into the CPU's cache

Comment: Is this a "one-off fix" you need to do or a process you need to put in place for a rolling-delete over time

Comment: bug fixed. unfortunately.. i said 1000 table only .. in reality.. there is 10k tables created due to wrong code.. no the thing is have to delete 10k tables :(

Comment: If this is a one-off, you could create the `DELETE` or `DROP` statements in C#, in a single SQL script. I suspect the original problem was caused by such scripts though.

Comment: If your database contains only these tables, it's much faster to insert the data into a new one (using a single table this time) and drop the old database altogether. Even if not, if downtime allows, it may well be faster to migrate the existing tables (or restore a backup) rather than delete these ones, since it'll be a slow process regardless. Of course if you need 24/7 uptime or your existing tables are large it's another matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a cursor in order to do that:

```
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE 'CIP_%'
```

Then do loop on it.

```
EXEC('DROP TABLE ' + @<yourFetchVariable>)
```

Comment: in c# i just take table name and split the table and i can find dates and can easly delete through c#. But i need using query even i don't know how to write  loop  in sql

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example that uses a strict pattern matching for the dated tables and extracts the date value from the name for use in the date range criteria (a single date per your sample data).

```
DECLARE 
      @StartDate date = '20221201' --ISO 8601 date format to avoid ambiguity
    , @EndDate date = '20221201'
    , @DropScript nvarchar(MAX);
WITH date_tables AS (
    SELECT name AS TableName, TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 11, 4)+SUBSTRING(name, 8, 2)+SUBSTRING(name, 5, 2) AS date) AS TableDate
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE name LIKE N'CIP[_][0-9][0-9][_][0-9][0-9][_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][_][0-9][0-9][_][0-9][0-9][_][0-9][0-9]'
)
SELECT @DropScript = STRING_AGG(N'DROP TABLE ' + TableName, N';') + N';'
FROM date_tables
WHERE TableDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
EXEC sp_executesql @DropScript;
GO
```